# card-footer not stay at the bottom of horizontal card bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using horizontal [bootstrap card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/card/#horizontal) and I want to align a text at the end of the second column. I tried to use `card-footer` but it doesn't seems to work [example](https://jsfiddle.net/quynt000/0t8y6uqm/19/). Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`card-body` and `card-footer` only automatically align themselves properly, and as Bootstrap's example shows when they are directly under the `card` class. However given your layout, you'd need the `col-md-8` to be a flex with column direction.

So add the classes `d-flex flex-column` to your `col-md-8` and your footer will stick to the bottom of the second column. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b2rhx4m/)